# Can't get element SELENIUM PYTHON

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to get element from page and then print it out
But it always print out this:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="636e500d9db221d6b7b10b8d7849e1b5", 
    element="4f0ccc3b-44b0-4cf2-abd4-95a70278bf77")>...
```

My code:

```
film_player = free_filmy_url + filmPlayerPart
dr = webdriver.Chrome()
dr.get(film_player)
captcha_button = dr.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div/input[1]')
captcha_items = dr.find_elements_by_class_name('captchaMyImg')
print(captcha_items)
```

Comment: Seems like it works as written. What is the problem? What did you expect? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the captcha_items and print each of them.

```
for captcha_item in captcha_items:
    # you can access each item here as "captcha_item"
    print(captcha_item.text()) # if you are trying to print the text
```

Answer (score 0):

Through your lines of code:

```
captcha_items = dr.find_elements_by_class_name('captchaMyImg')
print(captcha_items)
```

You are printing the elements.

Rather you must be looking to print an attribute of the elements and you can use the following solution:

```
print([my_elem.get_attribute("attribute") for my_elem in dr.find_elements_by_class_name('captchaMyImg')])
```

**Note**: You need to replace the text **attribute** with any of the existing attributes for those elements, e.g. `src`, `href`, `innerHTML`, etc.